# $fillable doesn't work when creating model from seeder

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

Why when I create a model from a seeder I get the error(`Illuminate\Database\QueryException`):

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, aaa, aaaa, null, aaaa, null, 2021-04-14 13:18:16, 2021-04-14 13:18:16). (SQL: insert into "users" ("id", "name", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, aaa, aaaa, aaaa, 2021-04-14 13:18:16, 2021-04-14 13:18:16) returning "id")

Seeder:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $user = App\Models\User::create([
            'id' => null,
            'name' => 'aaa',
            'email' => 'aaaa',
            'password' => 'aaaa',
        ])->toArray();

        dump($user);
    }
}
```

Web route(it works):

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    // return view('welcome');

    $user = App\User::create([
        'id' => null,
        'name' => 'aaa',
        'email' => 'aaaa',
        'password' => 'aaaa',
    ])->toArray();

    dump($user);
});
```

A similar error occurs on **Laravel** `^7.28` and `^8.*`(default installing).

I use **PostgreSQL**.

How fix it?

**UPD**:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

[I install the default laravel and run the default migrations by default. I am not making any additional changes.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Models/User.php)

Comment: @TimLewis I understand the error. Why does it work over the web route?

Comment: Please add your User model

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: I has a similar issue and I solve it by  adding `Model::reguard();`, from the post: [Fillable and creat() not working as intended?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fillable-and-creat-not-working-as-intended)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following line before you execute the query.

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::reguard();
```

Example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
   public function run()
   {
    
      Model::reguard();

      // Your Create query here
       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the 'id' key. Also, make sure the user migration doesn't have a unique constraint on the email column.

Comment: This is not the answer. There is no id field in `$fillable`.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси you don't know what you're talking about. The 'id' key needs to be removed from his seeder, if it is auto-generated by Postgres.

Comment: I agree that Id should be removed. But not by me, but Laravel. I'm using a model. And why does it work in web-route?

Comment: Why u specify the id if its auto increment?

Comment: @Localhousee 1. The identifier should be ignored. Point. Why else would $fillable.
2. Should I rewrite the question so other people understand the problem? The problem is not that I am passing in the ID, but the problem is that it is not being ignored!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array by fillable properties of the model using the `Arr::only()` helper.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        App\Models\User::create(Arr::only([
            'id' => null,
            'name' => 'aaa',
            'email' => 'aaaa',
            'password' => 'aaaa',
        ], (new App\Models\User)->getFillable()));
    }
}
```